# Django signals not receiving/working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am using django default receiver to handle signal. but its not working.
i have modified User model in APP1 whenver new User object create a receiver  in APP2 signal.py is listen to it, but its not working.

## app1/model.py

```
class User(BaseModel, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_paid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True) 

    objects = UserManager() 

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']  

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

## app2/signals.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from accounts.models import User    

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)#settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    print ("token generated")
    if created:
       print("data at signal ****", instance.email, instance)
```

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers creating user through admin

Comment: Uhu ? And are you sure that the users you are creating are `account.models.User` instances, not `django.contrib.auth.models.User` ones ? Also, are you sure that `app2.signals` is imported at startup ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers app2.signals is *not importd* in startup how to do this in **django 1.10**

Comment: This is documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how to import it on startup

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. Its because I'm not importing **signals.py** on startup.

## Working code

### apps.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.apps import AppConfig


class StreamsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'streams'    

    def ready(self):
        print("at ready")
        import streams.signals
```

### **init**.py

```
default_app_config = 'streams.apps.StreamsConfig'
```

after this change I'm receiving signals

Update:

As per django 3.0 documentation for newer applications adding default_app_config in init.py is not required if you are using dotted path to application configuration.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

Just replace

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 ...,
 'streams',
)
```

with

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 ...,
 'streams.apps.StreamsConfig',
)
```

It will work.

Comment: very important to remember adding the ```default_app_config = 'streams.apps.StreamsConfig'```